# Assigning set with a soql query

Tags: apex

Does anyone know why below code returns me with only 1 record

```
set<account> myset = new set<account>([select id  from account limit 100]);
system.debug('SETTT' + myset);
```

But when i say 'Name' to retrieve ,it gives me complete list.

```
set<account> myset = new set<account>([select id ,name from account limit 100]);
    system.debug('SETTT' + myset);
```

Find it strange,as ID is a unique thing and set should display all records

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is purely an anomaly of how the string representation of set looks when you System.debug it. All values are there for you to use in code.
Try:

```
set<account> myset = new set<account>([select id from account limit 100]);
system.debug('SET string representation = ' + myset);
system.debug('SET size = ' + myset.size());
for (account a : myset) {
    System.debug('an account id = ' + a.id);
}
```

Comment: Okeis.i found it strange as the same thing with map/list showed all values.But as in above code .yeah it does have everything

Comment: You are right, it does look different with name vs. id but this is just in the debug.

Comment: FYI this is still an issue as of 2018.