# Data is not retrieving in a set. Help me I am New to Apex

Tags: apex, class

I am new to Apex. When I query Accounts in a List it shows all the records in a list without for loop. But When I query the same in set, it only shows  One record. When I Check Size of the set, it displays actual size 100.
[image]

```
set<Account> setAcc= new Set<Account>([select id from Account where Name Like 'Test%' limit 100 ]); 
system.debug('Debugging Set of Account'+ setAcc);//Shows only one record
System.debug('Debugging Set of Account Size'+ setAcc.size());// shows actual size i.e, 100
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is a known issue, as explained in [this post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/13563/90910) by Doug B,
however, you can iterate through the set, and still get all records as expected.